# forecast per customer using AWS Forecast

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-forecast

I'm using AWS Forecast managed service for predicting customer expenditure over time.

I understand I have to create a dataset group that contains the datasets: primaray, secondary and metadata. (And then import these into the group)

One thing I can't get my head around is how to *organise* my datasets, and if I need a "Dataset Group" for each customer, or if I can merge all customer expenditure data into the same dataset?

As I understand a Dataset Group can only contain a single primary dataset (merged customer data in this case). However, the spending by one customer has nothing to do with the spending of another. If merging all data into a single primary dataset, can I generate forecasts by filtering on the customer ID **and**  these separate forecasts will not be related to each other in any way?.

Or, does this mean I have to create a Dataset Group per customer?

Comment: And I guess what I really mean is, under the hood does Forecast automatically create individual models on the "metric value" you can filter on (customer ID in this case)?

Comment: I think this is a much better way to put it, I would update the question to clarify it. Also, the accepted answer does not respond to it, since in principle one could still forecast per item but having a model trained on multiple inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If merging all data into a single primary dataset, can I generate forecasts by filtering on the customer ID

**Yes.**

> and these separate forecasts will not be related to each other in any way

**You can query and forecast per item**

AWS Forecast differentiates by three dataset types (target, related and meta) of which only target is mandatory.
Speaking for DEMAND forecasting, the target dataset defines theses 3 attributes: date, item_id, demand.
Further details on transactions will be stored in the related dataset.

I recommend theses samples:
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-forecast-samples

And for detailed explanation check out the developer guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/forecast/latest/dg/forecast.dg.pdf